# More space between dot and label of radio button

Tags: css, r, shiny, radio-button, radiobuttonlist

I'm having the following code:

```
radioButtons("selLang", "Taal:", choices = c("Gronings","Nederlands") , inline=FALSE)
```

in the UI of an R Shiny app, but found  the labels "Gronings" and "Nederlands" to close to actual buttons. It looks like this:

[image]

Is it possibe to increase the distance between labels and dots so that is becomes something like this:

[image]

Comment: You can do it through CSS. Please paste your CSS code.

Comment: Your radiobuttons look different from the code you sent. The solution has to be css

Answer (score 2):

**Use  `margin-right` and set whatever you want**
Here is example how to do it in css:

```css
input[type="radio"] {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked> Male<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other  
</form>
```

Comment: Tell me for more help

Comment: Thanks. Should I enter this: tags$style(type = 'text/css',  'input[type="radio"] { margin-right: 30px; }') ? Since I use Shiny, I would like to use the 'radioButtons' function. How it it possible to connect this with the css code?

Comment: Or maybe this: radioButtons("selLang", "Taal:", choiceNames  = list(HTML("&nbsp;Gronings"), HTML("&nbsp;Nederlands")), choiceValues = list("Gronings" , "Nederlands") , inline=FALSE)